# AngleSharp Parsing [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp

My HTML Code Is

```
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8" class="text"> 
     <B>Total</B>: 
    </td>   
      <td class="text">
          <b> 1 GB</b>
     </td>
      <td class="text">
          <b> 1.8 GB</b>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Now i want to get the data inside td tag having class="text".

In python i would have done this:

```
historySoup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = historySoup.find('td', attrs={
    "colspan": "8",
    "class": "text"
}).parent
tds = table.findAll('td')
puts(tds[1].text)
puts(tds[2].text)
```

But I'm stuck with AngelSharp.I tried this :

```
   var parser = new HtmlParser();              
             var document = parser.Parse(myhtml);            
             var blueListItemsCssSelector = document.QuerySelectorAll("td[colspan = '3']");
              foreach (var item in blueListItemsCssSelector)
            {                   
                item.GetElementsByClassName("text");
                var x = item.Text();

            }
```

But I am just getting total as text in x  and then the loop ends.Any idea how access the inner td tags of tr and store their text in a list or array?Also it takes time parsing any other method which is faster because my html contains more than 200 td tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you were doing it right ! In your C# code just add this

```
List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in blueListItemsCssSelector)
            {

                var x = item.NextElementSibling;
                dataList.Add(x.Text());
                var y = x.NextElementSibling;
                dataList.Add(y.Text());

            }
```